# Django curl request

Tags: django, django-1.6, django-request

Im trying to use curl to hit an endpoint in my Django application and havent been successful returning my data.

```
curl 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/?email=myname@gmail.com&part=123434
```

my server shows a 301 when the curl goes through, however; none of the print statements are ran in my view, and i am not able to get the querystring parameters using request.GET.get().

```
[21/Aug/2018 00:26:59] "GET /myapp/?email=myname@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

view.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        print('hello world')
        email = request.GET.get('email')
        part = request.POST.get('part')
        print(email)
        print(part)
        df = generate_dataframe('apps/myapp/data.csv')
        df = get_dataframe_by_part(part, df)
        bool = check_all(email, df)
        response_data = {}
        response_data['DoesUserExist'] = bool
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                      url(r'myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
                      )
```

myapp/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index', name='index'),
                       )
```

Comment: Did the view `print` the data?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge, no it does not. when I visit the page in the browser: json data shows, but it is all incorrect because I cannot query my email and part data.

Comment: even the `print('hello world')` not executing?

Comment: The code is fine, it looks like your url doesn't hit this method itself.. check that pattern. Which url have you added to redirect to the 'index method' and the respective method for  '/myapp/'

Comment: @SiddaramH, do i need to add querystrings in the urls.py files? I edited my question to show how my urls.py are structured... I can visit the site in the browser, just something funky with the querystrings.

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge , no it was not.

Comment: What's the response/result when you try via *browser* ?

Comment: Can you check this with postman? so that you can debug what exactly is the issue. Would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

The description for 301 error is

> The HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for
>   permanent URL redirection, meaning current links or records using the
>   URL that the response is received for should be updated.

from [301 error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Hence the issue could be different. check first, whether you can able to load from chrome  and the urls are correct